# Pip freeze vs. pip list

Tags: python, pip

Why does `pip list` generate a more comprehensive list than `pip freeze`?

```bash
$ pip list
feedparser (5.1.3)
pip (1.4.1)
setuptools (1.1.5)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

```bash
$ pip freeze
feedparser==5.1.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

---

Pip's documentation states:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| freeze | Output installed packages in requirements format. |
| list | List installed packages. |

What is a "requirements format"?

Comment: FYI, here are the [docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.4.1/logic.html?highlight=requirements#requirements-file-format).

Comment: [Up to date documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/) as of now.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

One may generate a `requirements.txt` via:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

A user can use this `requirements.txt` file to install all the dependencies. For instance:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The packages need to be in a specific format for `pip` to understand, such as:

```
# requirements.txt
feedparser==5.1.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
django==1.4.2
...
```

That is the "requirements format".

Here, `django==1.4.2` implies install `django` version `1.4.2` (even though the latest is 1.6.x).
If you do not specify `==1.4.2`, the latest version available would be installed.

You can read more in "[Virtualenv and pip Basics](http://jonathanchu.is/posts/virtualenv-and-pip-basics/)",
and the official "[Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/)" documentation.

Comment: Got it. Is there any particular reason why "list" produces a more comprehensive list than "freeze"?

Comment: i think it is because `pip list` lists everything, and `pip freeze` installs everything installed by pip.

Comment: Hm, that's a theory, but I'm fairly sure I didn't `pip install` `wsgiref`.

Comment: Python 3.2 includes `wsgiref.egg-info` in the Lib directory, which is why pip knows about it. You can't [un]install it with pip, and later versions of Python omit the metadata file so it won't appear.

Comment: you can use requirements.txt regardless of whether you're using a virtualenv or not

Comment: @nitrl some of the packages you see there were installed as dependencies to others

Comment: Is there a way to install the latest versions of the packages and not the specific ones, and is it a good idea to do so?

Comment: @leonid  if you get rid of the version number at the end , it would install the latest version from pypi. Read the answer completely

Comment: This answer doesn't address the most puzzling part of the question - why do the two lists differ? It only addresses the self-evident part of the question - requirements format is the format output by 'pip freeze', an example of which is shown in the question.

Answer (score 74):

To answer the second part of this question, the two packages shown in `pip list` but not `pip freeze` are `setuptools` (which is easy_install) and `pip` itself.

It looks like `pip freeze` just doesn't list packages that pip itself depends on. You may use the `--all` flag to show also those packages.

From [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/?highlight=freeze#cmdoption--all):

> `--all`
>
> Do not skip these packages in the output: pip, setuptools, distribute, wheel

Comment: `pip freeze` has an option `--all` to show also: `pip, setuptools, distribute, wheel` https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

Comment: less distribute

Answer (score 63):

The main difference is that the output of `pip freeze` can be dumped into a requirements.txt file and used later to re-construct the "frozen" environment.

In other words you can run: 
`pip freeze > frozen-requirements.txt` on one machine and then later on a different machine or on a clean environment you can do:
`pip install -r frozen-requirements.txt`
and you'll get the an identical environment with the exact same dependencies installed as you had in the original environment where you generated the frozen-requirements.txt.

Answer (score 31):

Look at the [pip documentation](http://staticbackup.readthedocs.com/pip/rtd-builds/latest/usage.html), which describes the functionality of both as:

**pip list**

> List installed packages, including editables.

**pip freeze**

> Output installed packages in requirements format.

So there are two differences:

1. Output format, `freeze` gives us the standard requirement format that may be used later with `pip install -r` to install requirements from.
2. Output content, `pip list` include editables which `pip freeze` does not.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable

Answer (score 21):

My preferred method of generating a requirements file is:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

This method keeps just the package names and package versions without potentially linking to local file paths which 'pip freeze' alone will sometimes give me. Local file paths in a requirements file make your codebase harder to use for other users and some developers don't know how to fix this so I prefer this method for ease of adoptability.

Comment: Wouldn't `pip list --not-required --format=freeze > requirements.txt` be even better since it only includes the top-level dependencies?

Comment: @dijonkitchen thanks for your input! I haven't done a deep dive into using this flag but I think it probably makes a requirements file cleaner and easier to understand. I am seeing some issues reported for it missing some particular dependencies which could be a potential issue but probably few and far between. Overall I'm in favor of explicit environment configurations and minimizing nondeterministic decisions so I would say in a data quality critical application like scientific computing it's useful to list all dependencies, but for most applications, top level is good enough.

Comment: Yeah, it may exclude some top-level dependencies if they are also nested in another one.

The only problem I see with explicit dependencies all the way down is it's difficult to upgrade and you may have extra ones that are no longer needed when nested dependencies change.

Comment: I personally find this the most useful command for the reasons noted. Explicit and flexible between package managers

Answer (score 20):

`pip list` shows **ALL** installed packages.

`pip freeze` shows packages **YOU** installed via `pip` (or `pipenv` if using that tool) command in a requirements format.

Remark below that ***setuptools***, ***pip***, ***wheel*** are installed when `pipenv shell` creates my virtual envelope. These packages were **NOT** installed by me using `pip`:

```
test1 % pipenv shell
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /Users/terrence/Development/Python/Projects/test1/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_3/libexec/bin/python3.8 (3.8.1) to create virtualenv…
⠹ Creating virtual environment...
<SNIP>
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
<SNIP>
```

Now review & compare the output of the respective commands where I've only installed ***cool-lib*** and ***sampleproject*** (of which ***peppercorn*** is a dependency):

```
test1 % pip freeze       <== Packages I'VE installed w/ pip

-e git+https://github.com/gdamjan/hello-world-python-package.git@10<snip>71#egg=cool_lib
peppercorn==0.6
sampleproject==1.3.1


test1 % pip list         <== All packages, incl. ones I've NOT installed w/ pip

Package       Version Location                                                                    
------------- ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
cool-lib      0.1  /Users/terrence/.local/share/virtualenvs/test1-y2Zgz1D2/src/cool-lib           <== Installed w/ `pip` command
peppercorn    0.6       <== Dependency of "sampleproject"
pip           20.0.2  
sampleproject 1.3.1     <== Installed w/ `pip` command
setuptools    45.1.0  
wheel         0.34.2
```

Comment: pip list - shows installed packages, not ALL. Check official documentation and the answer from Daniel Lahyani.

Comment: @filler36: I thought that "installed" was implied, but nonetheless incorporated your feedback to ensure the ambiguity didn't create a potential confusion.  Thanks for your feedback, very much obliged!- T

Comment: "pip freeze shows packages YOU installed via pip". On Linux this is WRONG! Both list and freeze show ALL packages, including those installed by the system's package manager (which is NOT YOU). `pip freeze` omits only (setuptools, wheel, pip, distribute), but has an `all` option to include them. [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-all).

Answer (score 1):

```
pip list
```

List installed packages: show **ALL** installed packages that even pip installed implictly

```
pip freeze
```

List installed packages:  - list of packages that are installed using pip command

pip freeze has `--all` flag to show all the packages.

Other difference is the output it renders, that you can check by running the commands.

Comment: On Linux, both list and freeze show ALL packages, including those installed by the system's package manager (i.e. not installed by pip or by you). pip freeze omits ONLY (setuptools, wheel, pip, distribute).

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution. If you accidentally made `pip` requirements with `pip list` instead of `pip freeze`, and want to convert into pip freeze format. I wrote this R script to do so.

```
library(tidyverse)

pip_list = read_lines("requirements.txt")

pip_freeze = pip_list %>%
  str_replace_all(" \\(", "==") %>%
  str_replace_all("\\)$", "")

pip_freeze %>% write_lines("requirements.txt")
```