# Why doesn't setuptools 1.3.1 appear when I pip freeze?

Tags: virtualenv, pip, setuptools, distribute

I am running `virtualenvwrapper` and friends on Ubuntu 12.04 (virtualenvwrapper 1.7.1.2, virtualenv 1.7.1.2, pip 1.0, Distribute 0.6.24, Python 2.7). To be able to `pip install matplotlib` I need a newer version of Distribute/setuptools, so I do the following:

```
$ mkvirtualenv new_venv
$ pip install matplotlib # fails
$ easy_install -U distribute
# installs Distribute 0.7.3 in the venv,
# which then installs setuptools 1.3.1
$ pip install matplotlib # works
```

However, when I run `pip freeze` I get:

```
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.7.3 # here's Distribute
matplotlib==1.3.1
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.8.0
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.2
six==1.4.1
tornado==3.1.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Where is `setuptools`? I've tried just `pip install setuptools` and it also fails to show up there.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*pip* won't list packages that *pip* itself depends on unless you tell it to. You may include such packages by doing:

`pip freeze --all`

*freeze* lists packages in a requirements-format - for use in requirements files etc - while *list* is just that, a list.

See [Pip freeze vs. pip list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966564/pip-freeze-vs-pip-list#18966632) for more details.

Comment: `pip freeze --all` did now work with pip version `7.0.1` on python 2.7. I used `pip list` though and it worked

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu `setuptools` is installed by the systems package manager. So it is not listed when you `pip freeze`. While creating a virtualenv, you will get these messages

```
mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

If you do a `pip freeze` immediately after this, you will get something like this

```
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Here `setuptools` and `pip` wont be listed.

If you want everything you can do a `pip list` which gives something like this.

```
argparse (1.2.1)
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (3.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

Comment: What is the difference between `freeze` and `list`?