# Cannot get gcloud to work with Python and Pycharm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I am trying to connect to the Google App Engine Datastore from my local machine. I have spent all day digging in to this without any luck.

I have tried the approach here (as well as alot of other suggestions from SO such as [Using gcloud-python in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057935/using-gcloud-python-in-gae) and [Unable to run dev_appserver.py with gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584937/unable-to-run-dev-appserver-py-with-gcloud)):

[How to access a remote datastore when running dev_appserver.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572330/how-to-access-a-remote-datastore-when-running-dev-appserver-py/34575005#34575005)

I first installed gcloud based on this description from google:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

According to the description I should add the following to my appengine_config.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

If I do that I get an error saying `ImportError: No module named gcloud`

If I then move the code to my main.py it seems to pickup the lib-folder and the modules there. That seems a bit strange to me, since I thought appengine_config was being run first to make sure things were initialised.
But now I am getting the following stack trace:

```
ERROR    2016-09-23 17:22:30,623 cgi.py:122] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gcloud import datastore
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/gcloud/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2985, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2971, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3013, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2544, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2118, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2057, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 999, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.logging.client
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The `google-cloud` library is [not working on App Engine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1893) and most likely you don't even have to since you can use the build in functionality.

From the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) you can use it like this:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it this way:-

1.) Create a lib folder in your project path.

2.) Install gcloud libraries by running following command into terminal from your project path:-

```
    pip install -t lib gcloud
```

3.) Create an appengine_config.py module in your project and add following lines of code:-

```
    import sys
    import os.path
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

4.) After this, you can import like this:-

```
    from gcloud import datastore
```

5.) To save data into live google datastore from local:-

```
    client = datastore.Client("project-id")
    key = client.key('Person')
    entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
    entity['name'] = ashish
    entity['age'] = 23
    client.put(entity)
```

It will save an entity named Person having properties name and age. Do not forget to specify your correct project id.

Answer (score -1):

Old question but this may be worth including:

I'm unsure the state of your **requirements.txt** file but I scrounged mine a bit and noticed **setuptools** *was not included*.

`pip freeze` doesn't export **setuptools** [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837410/why-doesnt-setuptools-1-3-1-appear-when-i-pip-freeze)

Assuming you're following the tutorial, you likely installed those libraries **EXCEPT for setuptools** to **lib**.

I added **setuptools=={verionnumber}** to **requirements.txt** and that fixed this related issue for me.