# How do I retrieve the version of Selenium currently installed, from Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How can I programmatically get the version of Selenium I have installed in my Python environment?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As simply as

```
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__version__
'2.37.2'
```

or for command line:

```
$ python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
2.37.2
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I couldn't craft a Google query that would unearth the answer.

Comment: @nemesys That was an easy too, https://www.google.com/search?q=python+module+version :)

Answer (score 14):

Try using `pip show selenium`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can try:

1. `pip list`
2. `conda list`

Or for example on Mac:

3. `brew list`

And then check if and what version is in your installed package list.

For Conda, you might have different environments. Change it by `conda activate myenv`, where ***myenv*** is the name of your second or more test environments.

Answer (score 4):

Please use the below command to see the version of the libraries that would have been installed using 'pip':

```
pip freeze
```

It will list all the used libraries with their versions.

Comment: What `pip freeze` is and where for used is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49251593/8928024) at another SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Download pip to [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) and then pip install selenium through the Anaconda prompt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is some of this a (literal) command line?