# How to check what version of Selenium we have on Windows (not webdriver, just the Selenium version installed)

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, cmd

Do we go to the command prompt and type the following?

```
$ python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
```

I see the following error:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY34A.png)

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72029856/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may have ***nothing*** to do with Selenium, but instead the confusing and sad practice of including ***the shell prompt*** ("$" in this case) in such instructions (which shouldn't be entered). Isn't there a canonical duplicate for it? I can't imagine there isn't.

Comment: It may be from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428732/how-do-i-retrieve-the-version-of-selenium-currently-installed-from-python/20428836#20428836).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Python shell to determine the selenium version:

```
>>> import selenium
>>> print(selenium.__version__)
4.1.5
>>>
```

Comment: This could be interpreted as plagiarism of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428732/how-do-i-retrieve-the-version-of-selenium-currently-installed-from-python/20428836#20428836) (likely blindly copied off that page and posted here, without even looking at the result (revision 1)).