# Selenium opens only Google Chrome (using webdriver-manager)

Tags: python, selenium, brave

Im trying to run selenium on Brave Browser instead of Google Chrome.
As the docs indicate in (https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#use-with-edge), I should input this exactly and Brave Browser will run, except it wont at all, it will run only Google Chrome

This is the code im using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as BraveService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType
import time, urllib3.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=BraveService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.BRAVE).install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(5)
```

It will only run Google Chrome instead of Brave Browser, anyone could please try and help me out to run on Brave Browser using webdriver_manager?
Thanks

Comment: Did you pay attention to the version? Which version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Well I installed selenium using pip3 this day exactly, which means its up to date, as per Brave Browser I also updated it today. Which means both are at the same version supposedly, im not sure how can I check tho.

Comment: Check the version of the selenium. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20428836/2681662
Then use he correct approach according to your version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Brave Browser installed on your computer, you can set the **binary location** of the webdriver.ChromeOptions to the location of **brave.exe** on your computer. In my case, the brave browser program is located here:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"
```

Here is an example of how to do this:

#### Code:

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as BraveService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=BraveService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.BRAVE).install()), options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```