# How do I get the list of third-party python packages that I have installed with pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows.

I'm not looking for the packages which are shipped with Python.

I just want the names of the 3rd party packages that I have manually installed using pip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) will do it for you:

```
$ pip freeze
docutils==0.11
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.19
Pygments==1.6
Sphinx==1.2.2
```

You will probably need option [-l](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-l) too.

Comment: To clarify dirrerence between ```freeze``` and ```list```: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49251593/747744

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pip list` or `pip list --local`