# How to find out if a module is installed on Python 2.7 Linux environment?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I can only login as a regular user on Linux, and a superuser has installed a module.

How to find out if a module is installed?

Comment: I just rolled back your edit as it changes the question to much. The already existing answers wouldn't be valid any more. You might want to ask a new question which specifically asks for at what date a module was installed.

Comment: "when" usually means "at what date or time", but the users understood it as "if", so the answers aren't valid for my question.

Comment: I think it's a language problem, I totally understand your intention. However, as far as I can tell, If your intention is "at what time and date" you should at least have written "when **was** a module installed?" I would advise editing "when" into "if" to make this question clear and fit to the answers. And again, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip freeze | grep <module>` should work. If you have Anaconda, `conda list` also gives you the modules.

Comment: pip: command not found. I know that pip freeze only displays the list of modules with their version numbers. I want to know at what date and time a module is installed.

Comment: Typically pip comes with python. Maybe try `python -m pip freeze`? You could also try just importing the module with `python -c "import <module>"` and look for an `ImportError`.

Comment: Did you meant that pip freeze displays all the modules installed with date and time? I'm able to import the module without any error. I just need to know at what date and time it got installed.

Comment: I see what you are asking now with your edited post. I've commented above.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip freeze | grep <moduleName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **pure python** on the command line:

```
python -c "import desiredModule"
```

If the desired module is already installed, simply an empty line is returned. If the module is not installed, an `ImportError` is raised.

This solution has the bonus of **working on all different python versions**, while the pip approach does only work when pip is installed (which is per default on newer version of python.)

---

**Using pip**, from the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/):

*pip list*

> List installed packages, including editables.
>
> Packages are listed in a case-insensitive sorted order.

*pip freeze*

> Output installed packages in requirements format.
>
> packages are listed in a case-insensitive sorted order.

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18966564/1251007) for a detailed explanation of the differences of `freeze` and `list`.