# Versioning issues about Django project creation

Tags: python, django

My Django version is 2.2.12. When I use the command `django-admin startproject mysite` to create a project, this project's setting.py shows me that `Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.13.`
I typed the command`sudo pip freeze|grep -i 'django'` into Pycharm's terminal to check the version and it also showed 2.2.
This thing puzzled me.

Comment: Maybe check installed version using `pip list`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18966564/1788851)

Comment: When I created another project, the db.sqlite3 file was missing from the project folder