Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Azure function python
I have a python azure function app.
It was working fine, until this morning.
func start runs fine, but when I run the listed endpoints, it throws this error:
An unhandled host error has occurred.
[2024-09-16T16:15:59.570Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been 
thrown by the target of an invocation. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer: Could not load file or 
assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.35.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find 
the file specified.

I don't understand this at all. I have no reference to this package, neither am I using dotnet.
All I am using is Azure function core tools.
How do I fix this ?

that's a .net error - how is your app set up?

@DanielA.White I used visual studio code to create function app project using python 3.11 and run it locally using azure function core tools.

You are using python function app, and why are you getting dotnet error?

@RithwikBojja this is what I don't understand. And out of nowhere it started showing up.

Try rebuilding the using pip freeze and then install . https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966632

Update your Function Core Tools npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true

@RithwikBojja rebuilding using pip freeze didn't work.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@RahulSharma Can you share the requirement.txt and function code?

@IkhtesamAfrin Sorry I can't as it is client code. But correct me if I am wrong, This file "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll" is part of azure function core tools folder. This file is literally present in the folder and yet I get this error. I create a new function app project and same happens. So there is something wrong with azure function core tools.

@RahulSharma can you try to uninstall the core tools and install again? Also verify if all the modules are being added in requirements.txt file. have you tried to run the function using Start debugging option in vs code? You can try func host start in your terminal as well to execute your function

@IkhtesamAfrin That worked, but there is a twist to it. Will mention in the answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

I Solved this issue with the following steps:

Check number of azure function core tools in your system and uninstall them.
Uninstall dotnet sdk.
Restart system.
Install azure function core tools again.

Error did mention there was a file called System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, which was not present.
Issue was 2 versions of azure function core tools were installed. Path variable was using one and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt file in azure function core tools was of the other version.
Going clean slate did the job.
Thank you everyone for your help!
